# I need help to turn some raw SQL into Eloquent code

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

As the title says, I'm having trouble turning my SQL code into Eloquent.

Here's the raw SQL:

```
select * from `students`
where (
    select status_student.id from `status_student` 
WHERE
status_student.id = (SELECT MAX(status_student.id) from `status_student`
WHERE 
status_student.student_id = students.id)
AND
status_student.status_id = 6
) 
IS NOT NULL;
```

and here's the code so far:

```
$status = $this->request->get('status');
if ($status !== "0") {
dd($query = Student::where(function($q) use($status){
                    $q->where('status_student.id', function($q2) use ($status) {
                        $q2->selectRaw('MAX(status_student.id)')
                        ->where('status_student.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
                        ->where('status_student.status_id', '=', $status);
                    });
                })->toSql());
}
```

which translates into SQL:

```
"select * from `students` where (`status_student`.`id` = (select MAX(status_student.id) where `status_student`.`student_id` = ? and `status_student`.`status_id` = ?))
```

so it's not working properly yet.

I'm having trouble introducing that IS NOT NULL clause and doing

```
select status_student.id from 'status_student'
```

instead of just

```
status_student.id =
```

How should I modify my code to get the desired SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code. And which field are you contraining to be not NULL?

Comment: @HuyPhạm I formatted it. The result of the where clause should have the constraint IS NOT NULL. (you can see that in my raw SQL query)

Comment: What happens if you put `->where('status_student.id', '<>', NULL)` to the chain? And why is not `null` condition is needed while it's being compared to non-null variable (`$status`) anyway?

Comment: I also need that subquery. If I write it like this: $q->where('status_student.id', '<>', NULL, function($q2) use ($status) I will get Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = request()->get('status');
        if ($status !== "0") {
            dd($query = Student::where(function($q) use($status){
                $q->where([['status_student.id' => function($q2) use ($status) {
                    $q2->selectRaw('MAX(status_student.id)')
                        ->where('status_student.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
                        ->where('status_student.status_id', '=', $status);
                }],
                    ['status_student.id', '<>', null]
                ]);
            })->toSql());
        }
```

Generated SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `students`
WHERE (((`status_student`.`student_id` = ?
     AND `status_student`.`status_id` IS NULL)
    AND `status_student`.`id` IS NOT NULL))
```

Not sure if I understanded you correctly but I assume you just didn't get the [syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) right

Comment: It isn't even close to the raw SQL that I needed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$status = $this->request->get('status');

if ($status !== "0") {
  // log the queries:
  \DB::enableQueryLog();
  $query = Student::with([
     'statusStudent' => function($q1) use($status) {
        $q1->where('status_student.id', function($q2) use ($status) {
        $q2->selectRaw('MAX(status_student.id)')
         ->where('status_student.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
         ->where('status_student.status_id', '=', $status);
        });
      }
  ])

  ->get();
  $pureQuery = \DB::getQueryLog();
  dd($pureQuery);
}
```

- If you would like to join in eloquent, you must use with() or load() to do that.

Comment: dd($query) returns "select * from `students`" only. Here's a bit of more code and my tables if you need them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904532/turning-my-raw-sql-code-in-laravel-orm-code-vs-using-it-raw

Comment: I updated my answer. for see all queries you have to use DB::getQueryLog() method.

Comment: I don't get the desired result when I run this query. Are you sure it is working properly?

Comment: what did you deceive as query?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Wgjfmwn I get this and it doesn't work as intended. If you can, please read this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904532/turning-my-raw-sql-code-in-laravel-orm-code-vs-using-it-raw you might understand better what I need. Right now, I don't get the desired values out of your Eloquent code.